Is this code thread-safe, given that it allows dirty reads?
Is this code thread-safe, given that it allows dirty reads?
It's not a map, it's a pointer to a struct.
I want to know if this is safe, allowing old variables to be read, is it safe if it is a string or a num?
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/time/rate"
    "sync"
)

var (
    TestLimiter = rate.NewLimiter(1000, 1500)
)

func UpdateLimiter(funcName string, limit int, burst int) {
    switch funcName {
    case "Test":
        TestLimiter = rate.NewLimiter(rate.Limit(limit), burst)
    }
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        if i == 4 {
            go func() {
                UpdateLimiter("Test", 1000, 1500)
                wg.Done()
            }()
            continue
        }
        go func() {
            if TestLimiter.Allow() {
                fmt.Println("allow")
            } else {
                fmt.Println("not allow")
            }

            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("done")

}

I tried to run it locally, and I didn't notice any panic.
run with go run main.go
but when i run go run -race  main.go, it's show Found 7 data race(s) exit status 66

You are updating TestLimiter from multiple goroutines, at the same time reading it. It is not thread safe, there is data race. You have no idea which version of rate limiter you are using in the reading goroutine.

Found 7 data race(s) tells you immediately that it is not thread-safe.

@BurakSerdar HI, Is this a problem when my program doesn't care which TestLimiter instance it is?

Yes. The behavior of a program with data races is undrfined. In practice it is lijely that goroutines do not see the updste to the shared variable.

What do you mean "thread safe"? It's clearly not free of data races. The go memory model provides guarantees about your program: arbitrary misbehavior is not allowed in your program (partly because you're updating a pointer, which will be a machine word in size), but possible behaviors are that the program can terminate if it notices a data-race and it may never "see" the updates to TestLimiter.
If you don't want to pay the (usually insignificant) synchronization costs of a mutex, use an atomic.Pointer[rate.Limiter] instead of a plain pointer, and use its Load and Store methods to read and update the pointer.
It's not your question, but personally I would use synchronization here. It's very unlikely that the cost of the mutex will be significant compared to the cost of Allow method call. You can use code like this:
type rateLimiter struct {
  mut sync.Mutex
  l *rate.Limiter
}

func (rl *rateLimiter) set(l *rate.Limiter) {
  rl.mut.Lock()
  defer rl.mut.Unlock()
  rl.l = l
}

func (rl *rateLimiter) get() *rate.Limiter {
  rl.mut.Lock()
  defer rl.mut.Unlock()
  return rl.l
}

func (rl *rateLimiter) Allow() bool {
    return rl.get().Allow()
}

var TestLimiter = &rateLimiter{l:  rate.NewLimiter(1000, 1500)}

and then use the set() method when you want to swap out the rate limiter.

"but the program terminating if it notices a data-race" --- does it?

@zerkms not sure what your comment means, but if it was that the text of the answer was unclear (which I think it was) then I changed the wording. If you're asking if a program can terminate if it discovers a data-race, then sure -- just read the go memory model document linked in the answer. "An implementation may always react to a data race by reporting the race and terminating the program. " (although I don't think in practice this would ever happen for code like yours).

@PaulHankin Why would you use a lot of code instead of an atomic pointer?

@eik because the concurrent behavior of mutexes is easy to understand, but atomics (with sequential consistency) are not. From the atomics package: "These functions require great care to be used correctly. Except for special, low-level applications, synchronization is better done with channels or the facilities of the sync package."

Cool, I know the correct way to handle the possible problems, but I'm just wondering if there will be any problems if I don't handle it properly. It seems that concurrent reading and writing still bring some hidden dangers. In addition, I use
TestLimiter.SetLimit(2000) TestLimiter.SetBurst(2500)
to solve this problem

@PaulHankin Interesting. You left out “Share memory by communicating; don't communicate by sharing memory.”

@PaulHankin the memory model says the runtime implementation "may" terminate. I'm not sure the official Go does that. I now see you added "can", it changes a lot, thank you :-)
